# Need a way of clumping columns together without trailing NAs and reversing the result

Tags: r

I am looking for a way of creating a new column composed of a set columns (bin 1-9 in this example) from an existing data frame without trailing NAs and the results reversed. All this without using loops. Thanks for your help!

data set example:

```
id bin_1 bin_2 bin_3 bin_4 bin_5 bin_6 bin_7 bin_8 bin_9
1   a     b     c     d     e     na    na    na    na
2   a     b     na    na    na    na    na    na    na
```

ideal result:

```
id reversed_noNAs
1      edcba
2      ba
```

I normally combine fields using do.call/paste but this clumps in the NAs:

```
do.call(paste, c(df[c("bin_1", "bin_2", "bin_3", "bin_4", "bin_5", "bin_6","bin_7","bin_8","bin_9")], sep = ""))
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your missing values are coded `NA` and not the string "NA", you could do:

```
apply(
    X=df[, grepl('^bin_\\d+$', names(df))], 
    MARGIN=1, 
    FUN=function(x) {paste(rev(na.omit(x)), collapse='')}
)
```

If your missing values are coded as strings, you could use `sub` instead of `na.omit`:

```
apply(
    X=df[, grepl('^bin_\\d+$', names(df))], 
    MARGIN=1, 
    FUN=function(x) {paste(rev(sub('^NA$', '', x)), collapse='')}
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you hardcode the column names. A more simple approach is to use `apply` to loop over the rows, and use `paste` plus `collapse` on each row, combined with `rev`. Removing the `NA`'s can be done using `na.omit`:

```
df = data.frame(matrix(sample(letters[1:5], 100, replace = TRUE), 10, 10))
na_rows = sample(1:10, 5)
na_cols = sample(1:10, 5)
df[sort(na_rows), sort(na_cols)] <- NA

apply(df, 1, function(x) paste(na.omit(rev(x)), collapse = ''))
```